# Matillion ETL- Multiple Table joins

Tags: etl, matillion

I am trying to join multiple tables using the gui. However, I am not seeing any options available. It's primarily allowing joining of two tables. In case we would like to join multiple tables, there's a SQL Task "SQL Component" available where we can write the SQL script to have multiple table Joins. Is there any other GUI options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matillion, there's no option available apart from the "SQL Component" . Please check all the videos of Matillion. I had a discussion with their customer care and they have confirmed. Multiple tables can be joined by writing SQL script in the "SQL Component"

Comment: While putting this comment, there was no option.. This got added after raising an issue with Matillion

Comment: I have been using matillion since early 2019, and this option has always been there.  Maybe you were on a very old version of Matillion (pre-2019)?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily doable and supported using the gui.  You can join as many tables as needed using the join component.  Just add each table in the join properties of the join component, and add the conditions for each join in the join expressions property of the join component.
[image]

[image]

[image]